# mySQL multiple cross reference select query

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to select the names of products stored in as an ID list in columns a different table. There are 20 columns to lookup so my normal approach would make a huge query. Can someone suggest a simple way to do this?

```
Table1:
id | productName

Table2
id | p1 | p2 | p3 | p4... up to p20
```

p1 - p20 each contain an ID number of a product from table1

I need to select rows in table2, replacing p1-p20 with the corresponding productName from table1

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for a concise query or a simple one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Can someone suggest a simple way to do this?

I guess this is a *simple* way:

```
SELECT 
    Table2.id,
    T1.productName,
    T2.productName,
    T3.productName,
    -- etc...
FROM Table2
JOIN Table1 T1 ON Table2.p1 = T1.id
JOIN Table2 T2 ON Table2.p1 = T2.id
JOIN Table3 T3 ON Table2.p1 = T3.id
-- etc...
```

Yes, this is a huge query, but it is simple.

---

You might want to reconsider your database design. Here's a suggestion:

```
Table1:
id | productName

Table2
id | index | productid
1    1       p1
1    2       p2
1    3       p3
...etc
```

Query like this:

```
SELECT id, index, productName
FROM Table2
JOIN Table1
ON Table2.productid = Table1.id
```

Comment: Yes, this was my 'normal' approach suggested in the question. I wonder is there a slicker way?

Comment: @cronoklee: A slicker way is to use a different table design.

Comment: Yeah I'm coming to the same conclusion - a new table design is probably the best bet